# Pass Environment Variable to Apache PHP Docker Container

Tags: php, apache, docker

I have a PHP script that needs to reference a variable I input at runtime.
I have built a docker image  (I cannot build the variable into the image as it changes each time):

Here's my minimum working example:

index.php

```
<?php
$name = $_ENV["name"];
echo $name;
?>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM PHP:apache

COPY index.php /var/www/html
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I'm trying to spin it up with:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 myimage:latest -e name=James
```

However, this fails as apache seems to have a flag called `-e` which reads the log level.

I'm sure I'm missing something fairly simple here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the flag before the docker image name as anything after the image name will be treated as [cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) when starting the docker container.

With that being said, please try to create the container using the following command

```
docker run -d -e name=James -p 80:80 myimage:latest
```

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) for more info.